# WiFi dongle for OSX with WPA2 enterprise support

Tags: macos, wifi

by any chance does anybody know which wifi usb adapter can I use to get connected to a network with WPA2 enterprise encryption (both password and username needed for login) on a Mac (OS X Mavericks in particular). I don't care much about the speed.

I have tried to use edimax ew-7811un, but it seems to work only with networks which only require a password to log in. Therefore it wouldn't connect to a university network, for example.

Comment: Do you know if your university network is configured to allow Macs to connect? Are Macs supported?

Comment: yes sure. I was able to connect to the university network at times when I was using the same macbook with its own built-in wifi. But after it stopped functioning I started to use a wifi dongle.

Comment: edimax ew-7811un: Supports 64/128-bit WEP, WPA , WPA2 encryption and WPS-compatible. What does your U recommend?  I visit U's help center. See if they can advise on a known working adapter.  I think it's more of an macOS software issue.